# Merge two objects inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following array:

```
[
    {
        "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "mark": 5,
        "date": "2018-11-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "mark": 2,
        "date": "2018-11-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "mark": 1,
        "date": "2018-12-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "mark": 2,
        "date": "2018-12-27T00:00:00.000Z",
    }
]
```

And i want to merge the object based on **idItem** and **date** and calculate the average mark so i can have the following:

```
[
    {
        "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "mark": 3.5,
        "date": "2018-11-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "mark": 1.5,
        "date": "2018-12-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: what is the expected result

Comment: @JasperBernales see the question

Comment: @Ayoubk Shouldn't the mark be `3.5` for the first object in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im using lodash [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy).

```
Object.entries(_.groupBy([
    {
        "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "mark": 5,
        "date": "2018-11-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "mark": 2,
        "date": "2018-11-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "mark": 1,
        "date": "2018-12-27T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
        "mark": 2,
        "date": "2018-12-27T00:00:00.000Z",
    }
], e => `${e.idItem}_${e.date}`)).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  const mark = value.reduce((sum, el) => sum + el.mark, 0) / value.length
 const [idItem, date] = key.split('_')
  return [...acc, { idItem, date, mark }]
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const input = [
  { idItem: "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1", mark: 5, date: "2018-11-27T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { idItem: "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1", mark: 2, date: "2018-11-27T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { idItem: "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1", mark: 1, date: "2018-12-27T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { idItem: "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1", mark: 2, date: "2018-12-27T00:00:00.000Z" }
];

const ids = new Set(input.map(e => `${e.idItem} ${e.date}`));
const grouped = [...ids].map(id => input.filter(
  e => `${e.idItem} ${e.date}` === id
)).map(
  group => ({
    ...group[0],
    mark: group.reduce((acc, cur) => cur.mark + acc, 0) / group.length,
  })
);
```

You can see the result logged out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-euclid-6cg1j)

Probably not the most performant, but it works.  First we get a set of all the combinations of id and date, then filter the input for each combination.  For each group we then copy the date and id over to the result, and reduce the entries to get the average.

Answer (score 1):

If id and date strings don't have a comma (`,`) in them, then you can use this solution, I first generate an object where the keys are a concatenation of the id and the date, and the values are objects that have the number of elements that have the id and date of the key, and the sum of their marks, this object will then be used to construct the desired array:

```js
var arr = [
  { "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1", "mark": 5, "date": "2018-11-27T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1", "mark": 2, "date": "2018-11-27T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1", "mark": 1, "date": "2018-12-27T00:00:00.000Z" },
  { "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1", "mark": 2, "date": "2018-12-27T00:00:00.000Z" }
];

var obj = {};

arr.forEach((o) => {
  var k = o.idItem + ',' + o.date;
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    obj[k].s += o.mark;
    obj[k].n += 1;
  } else {
    obj[k] = {s: o.mark, n: 1};
  }
});

var result = [];

Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => {
  var p = k.split(',');
  result.push({idItem: p[0], date: p[1], mark: obj[k].s / obj[k].n})
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll declare the array we will be using in this example:

```
var array = [
   {
      "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
      "mark": 5,
      "date": "2018-11-27T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
      "mark": 2,
      "date": "2018-11-27T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
      "mark": 1,
      "date": "2018-12-27T00:00:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "idItem": "5d656f10394d6524c821f1b1",
      "mark": 2,
      "date": "2018-12-27T00:00:00.000Z",
   }
];
```

So, here's the situation: I have one program that does work, but another implementation that **almost** works. I'll start with the one that does work, and it uses the `alasql` library:

To load the dependency, use the following `<script>` tag:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alasql@0.4">
```

Implementation:

```
var newArray = alasql('SELECT idItem, AVG([mark]) AS [mark], date AS [date] 
FROM ? GROUP BY date',[array]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray));
```

This next program only calculates the average mark for all IDs not taking into account the date (so the resulting average is 2.5). Perhaps someone can figure out how to properly run this program and edit my answer:

```
var sum = {};
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   var ele = array[i];
   if (!sum[ele.idItem]) {
      sum[ele.idItem] = {};
      sum[ele.idItem]["sum"] = 0;
      sum[ele.idItem]["count"] = 0;
   }
   sum[ele.idItem]["sum"] += ele.mark;
   sum[ele.idItem]["count"]++;
}
var result = [];
for (var idItem in sum) {
    result.push({idItem: idItem, mark: sum[idItem]["sum"] / sum[idItem]["count"]});
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```